# Angular http get params aren't getting through

Tags: php, angularjs, http-get

I notice my get-data isn't passed through in my GET request. I've stripped it down to:

```
$http({
  url: "http://www.myurl.com/somefolder/demo.php",
  method: "GET",
  data: { info: "lala"},
  timeout: 5000
})
.then(function (res) {
   var data = res.data;
   console.log((data));
},function (error) {
  alert("Something went wrong");
})
```

demo.php only contains:

```
<?php var_dump($_GET) ?>
```

It does work when I visit the URL with my browser, but via the http-get, everything seems fine but the data is never past.
`console.log(data)` always returns `array(0) {}` as if I didn't send any data.

Don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using this in an Angular based Ionic-app, and I'm testing it in my browser.
It's puzzling me for hours now...

Comment: I ended up putting my params in the url `http://www.myurl.com/somefolder/demo.php?info=lala`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the configuration object, `data` represents the body of the request (Used by a POST request for example). It seems that you want to add parameters to the URL. You should use `params` key instead.

```
$http({
  url: "http://www.myurl.com/somefolder/demo.php",
  method: "GET",
  params: { info: "lala"},
  timeout: 5000
})
```

More details here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage